# Eurosign in alignment is not showing up

Tags: symbols

The eurosign is not showing up as I wanted in the following alignment-context:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter\let\TTTemp\cap\makeatother
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\makeatletter\let\cap\TTTemp\makeatother
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \textcjheb{n}(\euro)\triangleright []\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @egreg: \textcjheb{n}(\euro) as I have is what I want. Is shall give me Hebrew nun (the Euro sign).

Comment: `\mbox{\euro}` when it's in math mode.

Comment: @egreg: That does not work for me.

Comment: @user24406 `\textcjheb{n}(\mbox{\euro})\triangleright []` works for me.

Comment: @egreg: Please indicate where I can find the answer you think I duplicate.

Comment: @egreg: It is not quite clear to me that my question duplicates the one you linked to. The solution given me here by you and 24406 seems different from and simpler than the answer accepted there.

Comment: @user24406 `\text{\euro}` and `\mbox{\euro}` are equivalent if not in a subscript or superscript. I suggested `\mbox` as the simplest solution (but, perhaps, too simple); in the linked question there are better ones.